# Any more or less official way to use class instead of className attribute in React

Tags: reactjs

I wonder if there's more or less official way to use `class` attribute instead of `className` in React.

And use normal names in style attribute `{{ 'background-color': 'red' }}` instead of its camel cased version `{{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}`.

Ideally with TypeScript support.

Comment: you have to be careful about using object literals for your styles. The reason for this is described amongst others here, https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is already supported in React 16 onwards, maybe not quite in the way you are expecting in your question. The style will not be processed as an JSX but as a string. In 15 the class attribute was ignored while in 16 it will be passed on

Refer the documentation for an explanation why this was changed. 
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Below snippet uses React 16

```js
function MyComponent(props){
  return <div class="myclass">Color Will be Red</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<style>
.myclass {
  color: red
}
</style>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Below snippet uses React 15

```js
function MyComponent(props){
  return <div class="myclass">Color Will not be Red</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<style>
.myclass {
  color: red
}
</style>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can already use kebab case (e.g. `'background-color'`) in JSX style tags without issue, but using `class` in lieu of `className` is strongly discouraged in React.

The reason for the latter is that although the [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) your React components looks similar to HTML, it is actually an extension of JavaScript. Because `class` is a keyword in JavaScript, React throws a warning when you use it in JSX:

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?

If you still want to use `class` for CSS class names, you can use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute to set HTML from JSX. Use of this attribute isn't recommended for most use cases including yours, but it won't throw a warning:

```
const DivWithInnerHTML = () => (
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        <div class="css-class-name" style="background-color: red;">
          html text
        </div>
      `
    }}
  />
);
```